# Ubuntu 20.04 Install Only Loads from Recovery Mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2

I've attempted to install Ubuntu 20.04 multiple times now with little success. I'm setting up a dual-boot with windows on this machine, and I have successfully performed this task on my previous laptop. I can install, however after rebooting, my machine goes to a purple screen and stays there. I can actually log in and see the desktop wallpaper, but I cannot see the taskbar, header, icons, etc. only the wallpaper. No other windows can be opened. I can successfully load and use Ubuntu by loading through recovery mode.

Running the boot-repair program claims 25 packages are broken. I ran the recommended repairs and I got the following link: (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MMgfcm4kV5/) for info on the repairs.

Assuming my AMD gpu drivers were the issue, I've attempted this with no success: (https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/ubantu-installation-graphics-card.html)

I have tried to remove Nvidia drivers, but none appear to have been installed initially.

I have also tried to install Ubuntu 18.04, but I had the same issue.

Hardware: (MSI X570 Tomahawk, Ryzen 9 5950X, Sapphire Radeon RX 6900XT).

Any help would be much appreciated. I have been scouring forums for hours with no success